# Download and replace Android resource files

Tags: android, resources

My application will have some customisation for each company that uses it. Up until now, I have been loading images and strings from resource files. The idea is that the default resources will be distributed with the application and company specific resources will be loaded from our server after they click on a link from an email to launch the initialisation intent. Does anyone know how to replace resource files? I would really like to keep using resource files to avoid rewriting a lot of code/XML.

I would distribute the application from our own server, rather than through the app store, so that we could have one version per company, but unfortunately this will give quite nasty security warnings that would concern our customers.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Does anyone know how to replace
>   resource files?

It is not possible, except by deploying an updated APK. APKs are digitally signed and cannot be modified at runtime.

Comment: Is it possible to replace the resources onDestroy?

As in, the customer wants to see a change, so they kill the app (possibly with a button) and restart?

I know this question is old, but we are attempting something similar.  On our QA builds that we ship to companies we would like to be able to remotely update their build without having to completely rebuild and QA a completely new change on a completely new build.

Comment: @petestmart: "Is it possible to replace the resources onDestroy?" -- no. "On our QA builds that we ship to companies we would like to be able to remotely update their build without having to completely rebuild and QA a completely new change on a completely new build" -- anything that needs to change without a rebuild needs to be obtained from some sort of Web service or similar dynamic data source. It cannot be code, resources, or assets, which cannot be modified at runtime.

Comment: Correct, our changes would actually be downloaded from a web service.

Comment: @petestmart: That's fine, but they cannot replace code, resources, assets, or anything else that is built into the APK. You are welcome to use resources as a fallback if you do not have this runtime-retrieved data, but you cannot replace the compiled-in resources at runtime.

Comment: Interesting. Thank you for your comments!

Answer (score 7):

No it is not possible, but here is what you can do instead... Copy your images etc in the Assets folder.. From the assets folder , copy them at runtime in the Application dir.. ie data/data/yourapppackage/yourresourcefolder
Use the images etc from the runtime folder.. Ie In code say,.. `imageView.setBackgroundDrawable(data/data/apppackagename/download/themename/resourcename)`...
Now when you download your resources from a runtime path , keep an XML file with key names and path for the image as key value pairs.. Have approprite Enums for that in code and store the image paths in HashMap at runtime..

Comment: So, basically, you are suggesting that instead of using Android's [resource](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/resources-i18n.html) system, to just use their file storage instead?

Comment: I would upvote this answer, except that your first sentence says "Yes its possible", when it actually can't be done and this is just a work around. If you correct this, then I will upvote it

Comment: @Casebash i dint get by what you mean by "If you correct this"..So basically you cannot replace the drawable folder ie resource folder , but can refer to images taken from runtime path .So by its possible i did not mean , replacing the images from resource folder but solution for replacing the images at runtime is possible provided you supply the runtime path.. Sorry for all the inconvenience caused. :)
Thanks,
Alok.

Comment: Your answer would be clearer if it said something like: "No it is not possible, but here is what you can do instead."

Comment: @Casebash :) :) will take care next time :)