# Dynamically replacing the xml file in android application

Tags: android

Is it possible to replace the xml file in values folder through code dynamically?

Answer (score 1):

No. It is not possible. Simply no res file can be edited dynamically.

For more info on it, refer to this question [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2069671/603744)

And also as commonsware suggests [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2823785/603744)